# Does anyone know why some images get a grainy "halo" when uploaded to the web - NOT a low resolution image

Tags: website-design, text, images

*I have a thorough understanding of high resolution vs low resolution photos, print vs web resolution etc, that shouldnt be the problem here, at least not entirely.*

Does anyone know why some photos get a grainy "halo" around the edges of objects within a photograph when you export them for web? And/or what that pattern/issue is called? See my example below. Along the edge of the passport seal, its extra grainy and pixelated. I highlighted a portion of it in yellow, but if you look closely, it's happening around the entire seal. It also appears around the "United States". This is the most recent example I have but its been a random problem for me forever, usually around edges and text in photographs. I dont know what its called to google it myself either. [image]

Comment: Appears to be jpg artifacts. Are you saving jpgs as jpgs?

Comment: Yes Im saving from Jpg to jpg. Ill look into jpg artifacts.

Answer (score 2):

This could have to do with the setup on the website. Another comment pointed out that they look like jpeg artifacts.

Your original may have been a high-quality jpeg, but many sites have "image optimizers" that may automatically downgrade image quality in order to reduce file size. You can try downloading the image that's served up with the right-click context menu and see whether the file size is significantly smaller.

If so, the server probably downgraded image quality for the sake of fast download.